# Unstructured Actionscript file and ActionScript Class?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe

I am new in ActionScript . I want to know that when should we use an Unstructured ActionScript file and when should we make a Class of ActionScript file? Does it effect the performance of Application ?If yes , HOW??? Please help me finding the comprehensive answer of above question.
Thanks!
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only think of a handful of instances in which it might make sense to use a non-class based structure in an ActionScript project:

1. You're quickly prototyping a simple piece of functionality (even then it's just as easy, assuming you're using ActionScript 3.0, to put your code in a class and set it as the Document as it is to use a non-class file via include)
2. You're dealing with non-class based legacy code
3. You're using the timeline to structure your code (usually not a great idea for anything much more complicated than a banner)
4. You're writing your project in ActionScript 1.0 (in which case you should really consider upgrading)

In all other cases, the tiny hit in performance resulting from the additional scaffolding of a class-based system will be more than offset by the advantages of it being well-structured.

If you're using Flex, I think you'll have to work quite hard not to use classes.